# Remove zone block from bind config file by pattern from the command line

Tags: bash, perl, sed, pattern-matching, bind

I'm trying to figure out how to make a script that will delete a specific zone in my Bind zone-file.

I have around 200 domains in my zone-file and I was thinking I could make a script that will delete a specific domain for me.
On my master server the zone-file looks like this:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com";
};

zone "example.net" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.net";
};
```

However on my slave there are two end-brackets instead of one.

```
zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.com";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};

zone "example.net" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.net";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};
```

So I could technically grep example.com, take that line and every line until `};` and delete. The same goes for the slave server only there it will have to delete every line until the second `};`

This would work on the master:

```
sed -n -e '/\"example.net\"/,/\};/p' zones.local
```

But not on the slave.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
The zone-file looks the same and there's no comments or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Perl for its recursive regexes. We can use them to match a brace-enclosed block, from an opening brace to the corresponding closing brace. For example:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/zone\s*"example.net"\s*(\{([^{}]|(?1))*\});\s*//g' foo.conf
```

The tricky part of the regex is `(\{([^{}]|(?1))*\})`. This is captured as capturing group 1 and referenced recursively inside itself as `(?1)`, so it matches a brace-enclosed group of arbitrary many non-brace characters and brace-enclosed groups.

As long as there are no braces in comments or strings, this should survive all your formatting changes.

**Update:** I had to look a bit, but there are BIND config file parsers out there that offer a more robust solution to the problem -- ultimately, regexes (even recursive ones) can carry you only so far and will break in some special cases. In general, it is better to use proper parsers for structured data like this, even if the code becomes longer for it. For example, with the [BIND::Config::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/BIND-Config-Parser/lib/BIND/Config/Parser.pm) Perl module, you could write

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use BIND::Config::Parser;

my $parser = new BIND::Config::Parser;

my $indent = 0;
my $ignoredepth = 0;
my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $domain = "\"$ARGV[1]\"";

$parser->set_open_block_handler(
    sub {
        if(($_[0] eq "zone" && $_[1] eq $domain) || $ignoredepth != 0) {
            ++$ignoredepth;
        } else {
            print "  " x $indent, join(" ", @_), " {\n";
            ++$indent;
        }
    });

$parser->set_close_block_handler(
    sub {
        if($ignoredepth != 0) {
            --$ignoredepth;
        } else {
            --$indent;
            print "  " x $indent, "};\n";
        }
    });

$parser->set_statement_handler(
    sub {
        if($ignoredepth == 0) {
            print "  " x $indent, join(" ", @_), "\;\n";
        }
    });

$parser->parse_file($file);
```

and call

```
perl remove_zone.pl named.conf.local example.net
```

This will nuke comments but keep the functional parts of the config file intact no matter what's in there that could confuse a regex. For automated use, this is the better way.

Comment: Very elegant solution. When I try it however, only the first occurance of the pattern is removed.

Comment: I added the `g` flag to the `s` command. It should work for all now.

Comment: This looks great but I just get the result output printed to the shell. Can I make it so it makes the change directly to the file?

Comment: Just do `cp named.conf.local named.conf.local~ && perl remove_zone.pl named.conf.local~ > named.conf.local`. You'll even have a backup.

Answer (score 1):

That zone file obeys the syntax of Tcl, so we can define a procedure named "zone" and read the zone file as if it's a Tcl script:

```tcl
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
lassign $argv domain_to_remove zone_file
proc zone {domain body} {
    if {$domain ne $::domain_to_remove} {
        puts [format {zone "%s" {%s}} $domain $body]
    }
}
source $zone_file
```

and then

```
$ tclsh remove_zone.tcl example.com zones 
zone "example.net" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.net";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow. Bind config files are TCL? I did not know that. I retract my shoddy brace-matching Perl and second this.

Comment: Actually, this is a bad solution: it will only print "zone" blocks and will choke on any other kind of line. I could write an "unknown" command handler, but Tcl will eat quotes and braces for the arguments.

Comment: Hum. But if the format fits this looks like it could be extended to a good solution. I'm afraid I don't know enough TCL to do it, though. I'll take the Perl back up for the moment; will remove it again if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This sed trick will work for both master and node, if your blocks end with a literal `};\n`:

```
sed -n -e '/\"example.com\"/,/^\};$/d;p;' zones.local
```

However, because this makes assumptions about how your file is structured, I would recommend the `perl` variant by @Wintermute.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you very much, it seems to be working only that I just get the output directly to the shell. Do you know how to actually make it manipulate the file?

Comment: `-nie` will not do what you expect. That will create a `zones.locale` file as backup.a

Comment: This also only works if the closing `};` is on a line with no leading or trailing spaces, which might work for this case but may not be universally true.

Answer (score 0):

sed is NOT for anything involving multiple lines, it's for simple substitutions on a single line. All of seds arcane language constructs to handle multiple input lines simultaneously became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, it's WAY past time to let them go:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/example.com/' file
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com";
};
```

With all of your samples in one file:

```
$ cat file
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com";
};

zone "example.net" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.net";
};

zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.com";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};

zone "example.net" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.net";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/example.com/' file
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.com";
};

zone "example.com" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.com";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};
```

.

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/example.net/' file
zone "example.net" {
    type master;
    file "master/example.net";
};

zone "example.net" {
    type slave;
    file "slave/example.net";
    masters {
            10.0.0.1;
    };
};
```

Comment: Bind's config file format does not require empty lines between zones, and you will have some trouble with subdomains this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If the posted sample input doesn't reflect the real structure of the input files then the OP can post a sample that does and we can tweak the solution to suit.

Comment: Balanced braces really seems like the only sane way to go to me. Awk, as good as it is for many things, is ill-equipped for this. EDIT: Actually, I'm looking for proper bind config file parsers because they're the only sane way to go. Balanced braces is better but also stopgap.

Comment: Not sure why you'd say that. Could you edit your question (or mine) to post an example that you think awk would struggle with but some other tool won't? Actually, let's let the OP do it if necessary as I suspect that like many "CSV" questions this is one of those cases where a fool-proof solution would require a language parser but the OP has a specific subset of possible constructs/layout and so will be happy with a cheap-and-cheerful solution just for his specific file and doesn't need something robust enough to handle all possible cases.

Comment: Put the last `};` of the slave `example.net` zone on the same line as the closing of the `masters` block, so that it reads `};};`. How do you match that as well as the old format in awk? The root problem is that the language we're trying to match is not regular. (In particular about your awk code: If there's an empty line within a `zone` block, which you really do have to expect, it will produce a broken config file and bind will not start).

Comment: A more complicated example would be where the file name contains braces too, e.g. `file "slave/foo};bar{.net";` (or can there be comments?) so let's see if the OP will post the most complicated example he really has to deal with in his specific config file(s) and we'll tackle THAT or just tell him to get/write a parser for that language.

Comment: ...you really want to parse *config files* by splitting them along empty lines? I'm sorry to say this because I know you know better, but the approach is bad, and I don't know why anyone would seriously consider doing this.

Comment: I really have no idea what `bind` is, it's all just records and fields to me and all I have to go on is what the OP tells us he has to deal with. I expect that what the OP has shown us in his question is exactly what he has to deal with and all the other possible complexity is simply a non-issue for him. If that's not the case he can tell us more but if he needs to deal with all possible layouts than it sounds like he needs a language parser so idk why we'd want to start trying to deal with some possible additional complexity but not others.

Comment: This is not going to be used to replace one occurrence of the zone once in one file, or the solution would be a text editor, so we're looking at a script that is meant to remove an arbitrary domain zone from a bind config file and that is to be used on many config files. In this scenario, some assumptions about the input are more reasonable than others, and quite frankly, the assumption that there are no empty lines in a zone block ranks at the bottom of that list. I'd take my chances with the sed solution before trying this. I don't like to do this, especially not to you, but -1 from me.

Comment: I think downvoting an answer that clearly, simply, and efficiently does everything the OP requested is completely unreasonable, especially when there doesn't appear to be any answer given so far that would satisfy every possible condition that apparently MIGHT exist in a `bind` file (whatever that is), but knock yourself out....

Comment: BIND is a nameserver. This is a configuration file for it. You can find out more about the format [here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/BIND/Tutorial), for example, but from the data shown it should already be clear that this is structured data that shouldn't be handled with awk or sed any more than should JSON or XML. This answer does not contain reasonable code to handle this sort of input, and I still don't see how you could possibly think that it does.